# How to handle failed connect of C# Selenium chromedriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the issue that sometimes our application don't start and therefore a connect of the Selenium will fail. It is OK for me that I get the error and the test fails.

My issue is in these case: That the following commands still starts the chromedriver.exe but I don't get a driver object back. So I can't stop the driver afterwards.

```
 _driver = new Driver()
            .SetChromeOptionsWeb()
            .SetDriver()
            .StartDriver();
```

Is there any possibility to not end up with a chromedriver.exe deamon process at the machine?

Thanks in advance
Nico

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround it into `try/catch/finally` block or just make use of `using`.

For example you could use this piece of code:

```
using var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com");
// 
//  some driver actions
//

// Here the purpose of this task is to keep the driver up.
await CustomTaskAsync(); 

// And here after last action the driver will be disposed
```